# How to copy matched line in less?

Tags: bash, less

I want to copy matched line that is too long that cannot select with the mouse in less, so does there exist another way in less?
For example

File: test.txt
content is:

```
line1: 12312sdfas23414123
liie2: aaaaaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfsdfsdfasdf
sdfasdfasdfadsfasdfdfdfd........
line3: 134sdgas1212
```

I will first search with 'aaaaa' and then how to copy that line to my clipboard?
After search, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626910/copy-specific-line-from-less , but I don't know how to apply this to my requirement. Thanks in advance

update:
Does there have some native ways? Because I found my Centos 6 doesn't install the xclip or pbcopy.

Answer (score 2):

`less` has a `v` command that will run the editor giving it the filename and current line number.
You can override the command it runs with something like:

```bash
export LESSEDIT='sed -n "%lp" %g | xclip -selection clipboard'
```

Now when you type `v`, it will use `sed` to print (p) the current line (%l) from the current file (%g), and pipe it into `xclip`, for example. You can write a tiny shell script, say `myless`, to hold this setting and run `less` for you:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export LESSEDIT='sed -n "%lp" %g | xclip -selection clipboard'
exec less "$@"
```

Don't forget to `chmod +x myless` to make it executable, and put it somewhere in a directory in your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

The link you send has the answer but I can include the exact sequence you are probably looking for:

The `less` commands to do that are:

1. `/aaaaax <enter>`
2. `| <enter>`
3. `head -1 | xclip -selection clipboard <enter>`

And this is what those commands are saying/doing

1. Search for the string 'aaaaax' which will put it at the top of the page/screen
2. "pipe" a mark. Pressing `enter` without an explicit mark just pipes this screen's contents
3. `head -1` trims the input to just the first line. In this case the line we want
4. `xclip -selection clipboard` puts that line on the system clipboard where you can paste it wherever

Comment: I would add that since some version `less` supports `&` command which is like `/` but displays only the lines which matched hiding all that did not match. This allows for saving matched lines if there are more than a single match.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to rely on `less` I recommend using `grep`.

You can filter the output with `grep` and may find your string faster.

Comment: I truly need the less, because there have multiple occurrences of search keywords in my file, so I should first locate the position that I want.

Comment: @YangXu are you aware that you can show the context around the match with `grep`? See `-A`, `-B` and `-C` in `man grep`.

Comment: @FelixJN Yeah, I know, but I think less is more fits my situation since I can locate what I want first, and then choose which I want as there will vary cases in that I cannot filter results with one keyword.